# stringTokenizer method error

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, stringtokenizer

I am trying to use stringTokenizer method for reading a 2D array stored in a file in the format..

```
1 1
1 1
```

the code is...

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
                for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
                    StringTokenizer tok = new StringTokenizer(in.readLine());
                    t[i][j]=Integer.parseInt(tok.nextToken());
                }
```

when i run this i am getting the java.lang.NullPointerException error.However if i use this in file

```
1 1 1 1
```

the code works!

why is it happening?

Comment: what is "n" set to when you run the program ?

Comment: @thinksteep exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException    java.util.stringtokenizer.<init><unknown source>

Comment: because you are running `i` and `j` both until `n`, it would only work on `n` by `n` arrays

Comment: @vivek my mistake assume n=2 in this case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By having your `StringTokenizer` object declaration/instantiation in the nested `for` loop the `StringTokenizer` object doesn't exist outside of the scope of the nested loop. So what this really does is just repeat the nested loop and so everything you read is horizontal only. If you move the `StringTokenizer` outside of the nested loop and inside of the parent loop it will still be in scope for the nested loop. That should fix your problem.

Move: 
`StringTokenizer tok = new StringTokenizer(in.readLine());` above your nested loop.

Comment: Happens to us all. Sometimes a second pair of eyes helps. :)